# How to change the background of about:newtab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to change the background of `about:newtab` in Firefox using the new [WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions). At the moment, I don't understand why I receive the following error message in the debug console:

```
Unchecked lastError value: Error: No window matching {"matchesHost":[]}
```

The code for my add-on is as follows:

*manifest.json*

```json
{
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "description": "Yourdomain description.",
    "homepage_url": "https://yourdomain.com",
    "icons": {
        "64": "icons/icon-64.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "yourDomain",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "version": "2.0"
}
```

*background.js*:

```js
var tabId;

function changeBackground() {
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS( tabId, {
        code: "body { border: 20px dotted pink; }"
    });
}

function handleCreated(tab) {
    if (tab.url == "about:newtab") {
        console.log(tab);
        tabId = tab.id;
        changeBackground();
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
```

Comment: Are you trying to completely override the page or do you just need to change the background color?

Answer (score 2):

### Currently no way for WebExtensions add-ons to change `about:newtab`

That is the error you receive when the page into which you are attempting to inject does not match the [match pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns), or can not be expressed as a match pattern (i.e. the URL must be able to be expressed as a [match pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns), even if you didn't supply a match pattern). Match patterns must have a [scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#scheme) that is one of `http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp`, or `app`. The error you are seeing is a result of not checking the `runtime.lastError` value in the callback function in [`tabs.insertCSS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/insertCSS) when the error is the one expected when you attempt to inject code or CSS into an `about:*` page.

The MDN documentation is quite specific about not being able to use [`tabs.insertCSS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/insertCSS) with any of the `about:*` pages (emphasis mine):

> You can only inject CSS into pages whose URL can be expressed using a match pattern: meaning, its scheme must be one of "http", "https", "file", "ftp". **This means that you can't inject CSS into any of the browser's built-in pages, such as `about:debugging`, `about:addons`, or the page that opens when you open a new empty tab [`about:newtab`].**

**Future:**
Chrome has the *manifest.json* key [`chrome_url_overrides`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) which allows overriding any of: `bookmarks`, `history`, or `newtab`. It appears that [Firefox support for this *manifest.json* key is a "maybe"](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/FAQ#Will_I_have_access_to_about_pages.2C_with_chrome_url_overrides.3F).

**Alternatives:**
It is possible to override the newtab page with [other types of Firefox add-ons](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910014948/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/13574/introduction#t=201709100149489262324).

You can use WebExtensions to detect that a tab has changed its URL to `about:newtab` and redirect the tab to a page of your choice.

### Using `tabs.insertCSS()` or [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) for tabs, generally

If you are using `tabs.insertCSS()` or `tabs.executeScript()` in a situation where the tab normally contains a regular URL, but *might* be an `about*:` (or `chrome:*` scheme on Chrome) (e.g. a `browser_action` button), you could handle the error with the following code (tested and working in both Firefox WebExtensions and Chrome):

```
function handleExecuteScriptAndInsertCSSErrors(tabId){
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
        let message = chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
        let isFirefox = window.InstallTrigger?true:false;
        let extraMessage = tabId ? 'in tab ' + tabId + '.' : 'on this page.';
        if((!isFirefox && message.indexOf('Cannot access a chrome:') > -1) //Chrome
            ||(isFirefox && message.indexOf('No window matching') > -1) //Firefox
        ){
            //The current tab is one into which we are not allowed to inject scripts.
            //  You should consider alternatives for informing the user that your extension
            //  does not work on a particular page/URL/tab.
            //  For example: For browser_actions, you should listen to chrome.tabs events
            //  and use use browserAction.disable()/enable() when the URL of the
            //  active tab is, or is not, one for which your add-on can operate.
            //  Alternately, you could use a page_action button.
            //In other words, using a console.log() here in a released add-on is not a good
            //  idea, but works for examples/testing.
            console.log('This extension, ' + chrome.runtime.id 
                        + ', does not work ' + extraMessage);
        } else {
            // Report the error
            if(isFirefox){
                //In Firefox, runtime.lastError is an Error Object including a stack trace.
                console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }else{
                console.error(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then change your `changeBackground()` code to:

```
function changeBackground(tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS( tabId, {
        code: "body { border: 20px dotted pink; }"
    }, handleExecuteScriptAndInsertCSSErrors.bind(null,tabId));
}
```

Obviously, changing your code like that won't actually allow you to change the background on the `about:newtab` page.

Comment: thanks @Makyen. When I insert your new function and modify my **changeBackground(tabId)** function I get the following message:

`alert() is not supported in background windows; please use console.log instead.`

So I changed the following line from

`alert('This extension, ' + chrome.runtime.id + ', does not work ' + extraMessage);`

to this:

`console.log('This extension, ' + chrome.runtime.id + ', does not work ' + extraMessage);`

As you already mentioned I can't change the about:newtab page with Web Extensions.

Comment: That is the [behavior I expected from `alert()` in a Firefox WebExtension background script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39084633/3773011). Forcing the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) open and having a line of text display is as close as we get to having an `alert()` in stock Firefox. [Although, I have written code which simulates an `alert()` modal window in a WebExtensions background script]. From your comment, it is clear the comment in the code that "this is automatically in the console, not an alert" was not sufficient. I will update it.