# How to create a bookmarks folder with javascript?

Tags: directory, bookmarks, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm looking at the MDN Javascript API example for bookmarks.create(). I'm trying to implement the example they have to learn how to make a folder:

```
function onBookmarkAdded(bookmarkItem) {
  console.log("Bookmark added with ID: " + bookmarkItem.id);
}

chrome.bookmarks.create({
  title: "bookmarks.create() on MDN",
  url: "https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create"
}, onBookmarkAdded);
```

This does nothing as far as I can tell. Any help or other examples of how to make a folder for bookmarks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Creates a bookmark or folder under the specified parentId. If url is NULL or missing, it will be a folder."

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your *manifest.json* file.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have added `"bookmaks"` to the `permissions` in your *manifest.json* file, then your code works as written to create a bookmark. Because your *manifest.json* file is not included in the question, we can not determine if that is the problem.

To create a bookmark folder, you either omit the `url` property or provide `url:null` in the object that you pass to [`bookmark.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create#Parameters)

Below is the complete, tested (on FF48.0.2 and Developer Edition, FF50.0a2), extension.  It is wrapped in code that allows creating the bookmark when a `browser_action` button is clicked. I find it easier for testing to have things execute when a `browser_action` button is clicked rather than just on install/Firefox run. It will:

1. Create a bookmark titled and linked: [`bookmarks.create() on MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create)
2. Create a bookmark folder `My Bookmark Folder A`
3. Create a bookmark folder `My Bookmark Folder B`
4. Create a bookmark folder `My Bookmark Folder B.1` within `My Bookmark Folder B`

All of these are created under "Other Bookmarks" because no `parentId` is provided when calling `bookmark.create()` for any of them which are not children of a bookmark folder this extension creates.

*background.js*:

```
//* For testing, open the Browser Console
try{
    //alert() is not supported in Firefox. This forces the Browser Console open.
    //  This abuse of a misfeature works in FF49.0b+, not in FF48
    alert('Open the Browser Console.');
}catch(e){
    //alert() throws an error in Firefox versions below 49
    console.log('Alert() threw an error. Probably Firefox version below 49.');
}
//*

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    doBrowserAction();
});

function doBrowserAction(){
    console.log('Background: Doing action');
    createABookmark();
    createABookmarkFolder();
    createABookmarkFolderWithinABookmarkFolder();
}

function onBookmarkAdded(bookmarkItem) {
  console.log("Bookmark added with ID: " + bookmarkItem.id, bookmarkItem);
}

function createABookmark(){
    chrome.bookmarks.create({
      title: "bookmarks.create() on MDN",
      url: "https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create"
    }, onBookmarkAdded);
}

function createABookmarkFolder(){
    chrome.bookmarks.create({
      title: "My Bookmark Folder A",
      url: null
    }, onBookmarkAdded);
}

function createABookmarkFolderWithinABookmarkFolder(){
    chrome.bookmarks.create({
      title: "My Bookmark Folder B",
      url: null
    }, bookmarkItem => {
        onBookmarkAdded(bookmarkItem);
        chrome.bookmarks.create({
          title: "My Bookmark Folder B.1",
          url: null,
          parentId: bookmarkItem.id
        },onBookmarkAdded 
        );
    });
}
```

*manifest.json*:

```
{
    "description": "Create a bookmark on browser_action button click",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Demo: Create Bookmark",
    "version": "0.1",

    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            //Firefox: must define id to use some features (e.g. option_ui)
            "id": "demo-create-bookmark@example.com",
            "strict_min_version": "48.0"
        }
    },

    "permissions": [
        "bookmarks"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "32": "myIcon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Do Action",
        "browser_style": true
    }
}
```

Obviously, if you are going to use the various functions for more than a demo, you will want to make them more general purpose (i.e. passing callbacks, bookmark properties, etc.).

Note: Please see the section titled ["General notes on testing and development of WebExtensions in Firefox" of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152380/3773011). Your statement, "This does nothing as far as I can tell", implies that you are not looking at the [Browser Console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084633/3773011) for error messages or console logs.